# Is there a way to prove this?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I want to prove $(A \cup B) \cap C = A \cup (B \cap C)$ only when $A \subset C$.

I will really appreciate if anyone can help me out, because I'm completely stuck on this one..

Comment: $A \subset$ RHS $=$ LHS $\subset C$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Draw a Venn diagram. Colour in each side of the equality. Note which regions of the Venn diagram can't actually exist if the equality is an equality (i.e. the regions where the two sides disagree on whether it's coloured). Conclude $A\subseteq C$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

In general,
$$A\cup(B\cap C)=(A\cup B)\cap(A\cup C)$$

Answer (score -1):

If $A\subset C$ we obtain: $$(A\cup B)\cap C=(A\cap C)\cup (B\cap C)=A\cup (B\cap C)$$
Can you end it now?

Comment: This is one direction of implication. The way I read the question, we actually want the other direction (if the equality is upheld, then $A\subseteq C$).

Comment: @Arthur Do you want that I'll end my solution or do you want to make it by yourself? Sorry, but your words are something banally.

Comment: I'm just saying that when someone wants help proving $A\implies B$, a proof showing $B\implies A$ isn't always that illuminating.

Comment: "Only when" means implication in one direction, not both. We say "if and only if" precisely because "only if" by itself doesn't mean equivalence.

Comment: So just to get this straight: you believe that we mathematicians say "if and only if" instead of "only if" just because we like the extra words, and the two phrases actually mean the same thing?

Comment: No, saying "if and only if" means we say "if and only if", and saying "only if" means we say "only if". There are two equally important parts to the phrase "if and only if": the "if" part and the "only if" part. They both signify an implication, going in opposite directions. Having them both is what makes the phrase signify an equivalence. Having just one of them makes it a one-way implication (the direction depends on which of them you have). But if this doesn't convince you, we will just have to agree to disagree.